# How to describe this POST JSON request body in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I have a POST request that uses the following JSON request body. How can I describe this request body using OpenAPI (Swagger)?

```js
{
  "testapi":{
    "testapiContext":{
      "messageId":"kkkk8",
      "messageDateTime":"2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530"
    },
    "testapiBody":{
      "cameraServiceRq":{
        "osType":"android",
        "deviceType":"samsung555"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far I tried the following, but I'm stuck at defining the body `schema`.

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: get camera
  license:
    name: MIT
host: localhost
basePath: /test/service
schemes:
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /getCameraParameters:
    post:
      summary: Create new parameters
      operationId: createnew
      consumes:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      parameters:
        - name: pet
          in: body
          description: The pet JSON you want to post
          schema:  # <--- What do I write here?
            
          required: true
      responses: 
        200: 
          description: "200 response"
          examples: 
            application/json: 
             {
               "status": "Success"
             }
```

I want to define the input body inline, as a sample for documentation.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I made it work with:

```yaml
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
        - text/xml
        - text/html
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            # Body schema with atomic property examples
            type: object
            properties:
              testapi:
                type: object
                properties:
                  messageId:
                    type: string
                    example: kkkk8
                  messageDateTime:
                    type: string
                    example: '2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530'
              testapiBody:
                type: object
                properties:
                  cameraServiceRq:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      osType:
                        type: string
                        example: android
                      deviceType:
                        type: string
                        example: samsung555
            # Alternatively, we can use a schema-level example
            example:
              testapi:
                testapiContext:
                  messageId: kkkk8
                  messageDateTime: '2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530'
                testapiBody:
                  cameraServiceRq:
                    osType: android
                    deviceType: samsung555
```

Answer (score 9):

`openapi` version >= `3.0.0` allows for the use of a [requestBody](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) which would allow for request body definitions outside of `parameters`.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
...
      requestBody:
        description: The pet JSON you want to post
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                testapi:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    messageId:
                      type: string
                      example: kkkk8
                    messageDateTime:
                      type: string
                      example: '2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530'
                testapiBody:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    cameraServiceRq:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        osType:
                          type: string
                          example: android
                        deviceType:
                          type: string
                          example: samsung555
              example:
                testapi:
                  testapiContext:
                    messageId: kkkk8
                    messageDateTime: '2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530'
                  testapiBody:
                    cameraServiceRq:
                      osType: android
                      deviceType: samsung555
...
```

Comment: How to display the required key in red for a particular property type. As shown here - https://redocly.github.io/redoc/#operation/newPet. I used "required: true" within `properties` something like this, but not working: properties:
                name:
                  type: string
                  description: Name of the user
                  required: true

Comment: How to submit `json array` as payload?

Answer (score 5):

The most readable way to include a multi line scalar into YAML is by using the [block literal style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688). This requires you to change your JSON example only by using indentation (which will be removed if you retrieve the value for the key):

```
.
.
produces:
  - application/json
example: |
  {
      "testapi": {
          "testapiContext": {
              "messageId": "kkkk8",
              "messageDateTime": "2014-08-17T14:07:30+0530"
     },
          "testapiBody": {
              "cameraServiceRq": {
                  "osType": "android",
                  "deviceType": "samsung555"
              }
          }
      }
  }
paths:
  /getCameraParameters:
.
.
```

(for clarity you can put an extra newline or two before the `paths` scalar key, they get [clipped by default](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688/chom) on the literal block style scalars.

Comment: Now when i copy the json in request body while sending the request it appends lots of  \t and \n  to my json object. How do I send a clean json to the backend

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the json is loaded from an external json file?

Comment: @Webnet There is nothing in the YAML specification on inclusion of other documents in a YAML document. So if there is such a functionality, it would have to be by interpretation of some Node by the application that reads the YAML document. If the application is in Python doing that is very easy.